# Is there a way to track any form being filled on google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is there a way to track any form being filled on google tag manager? I looked at the options, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, I can capture events for form submission, but not when the form is being filled by an user. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried to capture the event with input being clicked by the user, but it triggers on every page load. Check if one of the input field in the form is being filled.

Comment: You need to be more specific re/ what exactly you want to accomplish - e.g. checking individual fields as the user proceeds to the next field, or check all required fields before the form is submitted etc. There are ways (nothing built-in, though), but they depend on the expected outcome (also please finish you sentences).

Comment: I just want to check if one input inside a proper field is being filled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you generally have two ways of doing it: ask your front-end devs to write the code and just send you a dataLayer event when it happens, or write the code on your own.

If you're not able to delegate it to the FE devs, then you will have to write it on your own. Consider what you want to do. The simplest thing from here would be detecting clicks on that one field, assuming that if a user clicked it, then they will fill it. Tracking like this is not perfect since there are other ways to fill a field without clicking/tapping it And also there will be cases when a user clicks it, but doesn't type anything. But this is probably what you want to do. For this, you only need to pick a right CSS selector and use built-in funcitonality of GTM.

If you actually want to track when the field changes input, you will have to write your own event listeners and with it, send yourself dataLayer events and then listen to those and send the event accordingly.

This is what you want to know about the change event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

You will also likely want to prevent event sent on every change, so make a blocking variable that you set after the listener callback fires once.

This is very messy. It's not likely worth it to go this route.